# Angularjs How can I switch from one controller to another?

Tags: angularjs, controller

How can I switch my view from *LoginController* to *PanelController*?

This is my angular script:

```
app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http) {
    //stuff
});

app.controller('PanelController', function ($scope, $http) {
    //stuff
});
```

this is my index.html

```
<!-- LOGIN CONTROLLER -->
<body ng-controller="LoginController">
    <!-- stuff -->
</body>

<!-- PANEL CONTROLLER -->
<body ng-controller="PanelController">
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        Logged succeful!
    </div>

    <!-- other stuff -->
</body>
```

Comment: WHat are you trying to achieve by this ? Can you elaborate more as I think you are implementing things wrong

Comment: I am learning angular. However i'm trying to develop a single page app. After I pressed login button in LoginController, I want to change my page view to PanelController which show some account statistics. How can I do?

Comment: What you'e looking for is "routing". https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09. Sorry to ask this but, why are you learning AngularJS? It's dead. It's been replaced by Angular for some years already now.

Comment: @Vincenzo : I agree with JB.